# JSON Array to C# Array with LitJson

Tags: c#, arrays, json, unity-game-engine, litjson

I am trying to convert an array in JSON to a sort of array (Maybe a list?) in C# for a Unity game. I have tried everything I can think of to do this, but with no success. Here is an example of the JSON that I am trying to convert, without an array:

```
    [
        {
            "id": 0,
            "name": "Name 0",
            "description": "Description for id 0 goes here."
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Name 1",
            "description": "Description for id 1 goes here."
        }
    ]
```

And here is how I go about converting it to a list in C#:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using LitJson;
using System.IO;

public class BuildingSystem : MonoBehaviour {

    private List<BuildObjects> database = new List<BuildObjects>();
    private JsonData buildingData;

    void Start() {

        buildingData = JsonMapper.ToObject(File.ReadAllText(Application.dataPath + "/StreamingAssets/Buildings.json"));
        ConstructBuildingDatabase();
    }

    void ConstructBuildingDatabase() {
        for (int i = 0; i < buildingData.Count; i++) {
            database.Add (new BuildObjects ((int)buildingData [i] ["id"],
                (string)buildingData [i] ["name"],
                (string)buildingData [i] ["description"]));
        }
    }
}

public class BuildObjects {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public BuildObjects (int id, string name, string description) {
        this.ID = id;
        this.Name = name;
        this.Description = description;

    public BuildObjects() {
        this.ID = -1;
    }
}
```

If I wanted to add a new variable to the JSON like this for example:

```
[
    {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "Name 0",
        "description": "Description for id 0 goes here.",
        "properties": [{"bool": true, "string": "text goes here"},{"bool": false, "string": "more text goes here"}]
    }
]
```

How could I read it in my C# script? I have tried defining "properties" (With this line

```
(type)buildingData [i] ["properties"]
```

) as a bool[], a List with a new public class Properties (on which I got stuck), and out of desperation, an ArrayList and a BitArray.

But don't let my failure to do it with these methods deter you, if you believe you know how to do it as one of these then I probably tried it wrong. I'm quite stuck on this, any help you can give if greatly appreciated!

Comment: buildingData [i] ["properties"] is an object array than bool[]. buildingData[0]["properties"][1]["string"] should return you "more text goes here"

Comment: i highly reccomend this json helper class http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=JSONObject

Makes json in unity super simple.

Comment: Oops, I tried bool[] but realized I would need variables besides bools, shouldn't have included it.